# What Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 features do you need to install to get OLEDB Provider Linked Table Connectivity?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, connectivity, oledb

Which features do you need to install in your SQL Server 2008 R2 instance to get OLEDB Provider Linked Table Connectivity?

Specifically I'm trying to install the VFPOLEDB provider.  (And something tells me I also need a 32-bit instance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link below has the download you need:

[Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839)

> The Visual FoxPro OLE DB Provider (VfpOleDB.dll) exposes OLE DB interfaces that you can use to access Visual FoxPro databases and tables from other programming languages and applications.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the no-longer current VFPOLEDB provider.  See:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839

or

http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-OLE-DB-Provider-for-Visual-FoxPro-9-0/3000-10254_4-10729530.html

Yes, we still have a computer using that on SQL Server 2008 R2.  (But it is on the way out, of course.)

Yes, FoxPro is a 32-bit application and that will affect what you install and how you set it up.

Workaround for 32-bit on a 64-bit server.  Install an older 32-bit version of SQL Server Express for use in connecting to FoxPro. Then pull from the 32-bit SQL Server Express into your 64-bit server, using the standard linked server facilities.

Comment: Do you count the extra linked table as hop?  I guess it doesn't matter since there's still going to be more than one hop: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlupdates/2014/12/05/sql-server-kerberos-and-spn-quick-reference/

Comment: If you mean you are using a **linked server** (even though you are only interested in one remote table) then **Yes** that is a hop.   When using Kerberos authentication, you can continue to make hops as long as each server supports Kerberos authentication and is correctly configured.